# strtotime skipping month when giving starting date

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to jump from month to month, starting from a specific timestamp, but when I get jump from August, September always gets skipped. Starting From August 31 (1346389200) and jumping 1 month:

```
strtotime('+1 month', 1346389200);
```

yields 1349067600 - which is October 1st.
I've read all about strtotime making mistakes if it doesn't have a starting date to calculate from, but what could the issue be with this?
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get dates for first day in months? Is 31.Avg +1month = 1.Oct valid ?

Comment: @glavić no he is pointing that 31 august + 1 month = 1 october

Answer (score 2):

One month after 31 August is 31 September, but, because it not exists, php force the result to 1 Oktober.
So, you should force the current month on 1th day (of course if you want only year and month) :

```
strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date("Y-m-1",1346389200)));
```

but if you use php >5.3 you can use more reliable `DateTime` class and methods.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't use timestamps and `strtotime` for this comparison.  You will introduce problems because of things like daylight savings, leap years, etc. Best to use DateTime and DateInterval classes/functions to do this in a more thorough manner.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php